# Sort a Vector of Objects in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, object, vector

I have this Vector of Objects and each Object has some properities(date, name, id, etc.).

I want to sort the vector by, lets say, a date. How do I do this? I've seen, that an Array would support sortOn() function, but Vectors don't have it.

Object:

```
public final class DisciplineEvent {
    public var id:Number;
    public var name:String;
    public var date:Date;}
```

Thanx for answering.

Comment: IMHO in case of Objects, you'd better go with Array, as Object is a dynamic type, so natively using `sortOn()` will be better than any crutch with Vectors. Anyway any object can be derived to type Object, so making a `Vector.<Object>` is pretty pointless.

Comment: Agree with @Vesper here. Array's `sortOn` is *way* faster than any sort function of your own that you could use with Vector, and you're not gaining anything from using a Vector unless it stores primitives anyway.

Comment: Thanx for your answers. I've used the Marty Wallace's soluton, least complicated for me.

Comment: When you say 'you're not gaining anything', how do you mean? Obviously there's type-safety with Vectors, which is a big gain when working in teams etc, but I thought there'd be an overall performance gain as well, is there not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet for speed, access to Array's `sortOn()` and having a Vector as the result would be to just copy the content of the Vector across to an Array, use `sortOn()` and then copy the content back across. Example:

```
var vec:Vector.<Object> = new <Object>[
    { a: 2 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 12 }, { a: 7 }
];

var array:Array = [];
while(vec.length > 0) array.push(vec.pop());

array.sortOn("a", Array.NUMERIC|Array.DESCENDING);
while(array.length > 0) vec.push(array.pop());

for each(var i:Object in vec)
{
    trace(i.a);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have this vector:

```
var objects:Vector<ObjectType> = new Vector<ObjectType>();
objects.push(obj1, obj2);
```

You would sort it with:

```
var sortingFunction:Function = function(itemA:ObjectType, itemB:ObjectType):Number {
    if (itemA.date.valueOf() < itemB.date.valueOf()) return -1; //ITEM A is before ITEM B
    else if (itemA.date.valueOf() > itemB.date.valueOf()) return 1; //ITEM A is after ITEM B
    else return 0; //ITEM A and ITEM B have same date
}

objects.sort(sortingFunction);
```

more information can be found here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#sort()

Comment: Yes, or even better, declare class-wide (private maybe) function to directly pass to Vector.